# Stuck with an infinite loop and whitespaces detection c++

Tags: c++

This is the question that needs to be implemented:

> Write a C++ program that stops reading a line of text when a period is
>   entered and displays the sentence with correct spacing and capitalization. For this program, correct spacing means only one space between words, and all letters should be lowercase, except the first letter. For example, if the user enters the text *"i am going to Go TO THe moVies."*, the displayed sentence should be *"I am going to go to the movies."*

I have written my piece of code which looks like this:

```
// Processing a sentence and verifying if it is grammatically correct or not (spacing and capitalization)
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string sentence;
cout << "Enter the sentence: ";
getline(cin, sentence);
int len = sentence.length();

// Dealing with capitalizations
for (int j = 0; j <= len; j++)
{
     if (islower(sentence[0]))
            sentence[0] = toupper(sentence[0]);
     if(j>0)
            if(isupper(sentence[j]))
                sentence[j] = tolower(sentence[j]);
}

 int space = 0;
do
{
    for (int k = 0; k <= len; k++)
    {
        if(isspace(sentence[k]))
        {
            cout << k << endl;
            int n = k+1;
            if(sentence[n] == ' ' && n <=len)
                {
                    space++;
                    cout << space <<endl;
                    n++;
                    cout << n <<endl;
                }
            if(space!= 0)
                sentence.erase(k,space);
            cout << sentence <<endl;
        }

    }
    len = sentence.length();
    //cout << len <<endl;
 } while (space != 0);

}
```

With this I was able to deal with capitalization issue but problem occurs when I try to check for more than one whitespace between two words. In the `do` loop I am somehow stuck in an infinite loop.

Like when I try and print the length of the string (`len/len1`) in the first line inside do-while loop, it keeps on running in an infinite loop. Similarly, when I try and print the value of `k` after the for loop, it again goes into infinite loop. I think it has to do with my use of do-while loop, but I am not able to get my head around it.

This is the output that I am receiving.
[image: Check this out]

Comment: can you make your code a bit cleaner ? At least delete commented out lines ?

Comment: Why is this `if (islower(sentence[0]))
            sentence[0] = toupper(sentence[0]);` in the loop?

Comment: Well I guess that erasing some spaces in your string changes its length (e.g. the len variable is not updated)

Comment: In your `for` loop inside the `do` - `while` you increment `space` if you have more than one whitespace, which causes your condition for the loop to always evaluate to true

Comment: Instead of modifying the string as you try to iterating over it, perhaps you could only read from it, and write the correct output to something else.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @ВиталикБушаев Have done a few changes have a look

Comment: @EdHeal to check whether the first letter of the sentence is uppercase or lowercase

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi - It does not depend on `j` - so can be taken out of the loop - you only need to do this once!

Comment: Also this bit `if(j>0)` is always going to be true in the loop!

Comment: @UnholySheep I am struggling with 'space' variable. If i declare it inside the loop so that every time the loop is executed it resets to 0, the compiler gives me an error saying that space was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @EdHeal Thank you for pointing this out. Any help on whitespaces detection and reduction in case of more than one spaces between two words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few different issues with this code, but i believe that the code below addresses them.  hopefully this code is readable enough that you can learn a few techniques.  for example, no need to capitalize the first letter inside the loop, do it once and be done with it.

the usual problem with infinite loops is that the loop termination condition is never met--ensure that it will be met no matter what happens in the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string sentence;
    cout << "Enter the sentence: ";
    getline(cin, sentence);
    int len = sentence.find(".", 0) + 1;  // up to and including the period

    // Dealing with capitalizations
    if (islower(sentence[0]))
        sentence[0] = toupper(sentence[0]);
    for (int j = 1; j < len; j++)
        if(isupper(sentence[j]))
            sentence[j] = tolower(sentence[j]);

    // eliminate duplicate whitespace
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (isspace(sentence[i]))
            // check length first, i + 1 as index could overflow buffer
            while (i < len && isspace(sentence[i + 1])) {
                sentence.erase(i + 1, 1);
                len--;  // ensure sentence decreases in length
            }

    cout << sentence.substr(0, len) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You do not need  `if (islower(sentence[0]))` ditto with `if(isupper(sentence[j]))`

Comment: How about if the first character is a space? I think it should be skipped

Comment: sure, good point; simply uppercase the first letter--i was not focusing on that, but you are correct.  same with the lower casing--just do it!  thanks.

Comment: Ed, i was not trying to determine every possible case, rather to provide some instruction in how to make his problem go away.  while you are correct, we need to leave the real work to the questioner; we help 'unstick' him, not do his homework for him :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here goes

```
std::string sentence;
std::string new_sentence;
std::cout << "Enter the sentence: ";
std::getline(std::cin, sentence);

bool do_write = false; // Looking for first non-space character

bool first_char = true;
// Loop to end of string or .
for (unsiged int i = 0; i < sentence.length() && sentence[i] != '.'; ++i) {
   if (sentence[i] != ' ') { // Not space - good - write it
     do_write = true;
   }
   if (do_write) {
      new_sentence += (first_char ? toupper(sentence[i]) : tolower(sentence[i]);
      first_char = false;
   }
   if (sentence[i] == ' ') {
     do_write = false; // No more spaces please
   }
}
if (i < sentence.length()) {  // Add dot if required
  new_sentence += '.';
}
```